# In Excel, is there a way to autofill from the bottom up, versus down?

Tags: microsoft-excel

currently I have a column looks like this:

```
A B ...
1 A
2
3
4 B
5 
6 
7 C
8 
...
```

And I want to make it looks like this

```
A B ...
1 A
2 B
3 B
4 B
5 C
6 C
7 C
8 
...
```

Is there a way to finish the job quickly? Please note that my data is currently filtered by another field so this question needs to apply to VISIBLE CELLS ONLY.

Comment: If you can make only the hidden cells visible, then yes. You'll need to copy them, then do the job, then paste them back.